# Button not displaying in applet

Tags: java, applet, awt, keylistener, runnable

The following is the *condensed* code of my applet game:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Game extends Applet implements KeyListener, Runnable {
    Button options = new Button("Options");
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);

    public void init() {
        addKeyListener(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        // draw stuff
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                thread.sleep(40);
                repaint();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException exception) {}
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        switch (keyEvent.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE:
            // pause game
            add(options);
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent keyEvent) {}
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent keyEvent) {}
}
```

My game runs as it's expected to. However when the user presses `Esc` I want to pause the game and display an options button.

The problem is that when I press `Esc` it pauses the game as expected. However it doesn't display the button on the screen. I've tried to search for a solution to no avail. What exactly is happening?

Comment: What layout manager are you using?  What does you paint method do?  Are you calling `super.paint`? Also, I would SERIOUSLY consider using Swing based components of AWT, personally...

Comment: I'm using `BorderLayout`. However even if I use any other layout it still doesn't show the button.

Comment: What's you paint method do?  Does it call `super.paint`?

Comment: No. It doesn't call `super.paint`. Is it supposed to?

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), required in applets, too.

Comment: @AaditMShah YES.  Paint does a LOT of important work, including painting the child components!  You MUST call `super.paint`...

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Alright. I added the line `super.paint(graphics);` to the beginning of my `paint` method. However it still doesn't paint the button.

Comment: After you call `add` make a call to `invalidate` and `repaint`

Comment: @MadProgrammer - It still doesn't display the button. Interestingly if I move `add(options);` to the `init` method then it does display the button. However key events no longer work because it doesn't have focus.

Comment: In this millennium, use Swing components over AWT.  There is `javax.swing.JApplet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works perfectly fine for me...

```
public class TestApplet02 extends Applet implements KeyListener, Runnable {

    Button options = new Button("Options");
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    int y = 0;

    public void init() {
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                addKeyListener(TestApplet02.this);
            }
        });
    }

    public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        super.paint(graphics);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;
        y++;
        if (y > getHeight()) {
            y = 0;
        }
        g2d.drawLine(0, y, getWidth(), y);
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                thread.sleep(40);
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        repaint();
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
        }
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        switch (keyEvent.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE:
                // pause game
                add(options);
                invalidate();
                revalidate();
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    }
}
```

From the link TrashGod provided...

> In an applet, the GUI-creation task must be launched from the init
>   method using invokeAndWait; otherwise, init may return before the GUI
>   is created, which may cause problems for a web browser launching an
>   applet. In any other kind of program, scheduling the GUI-creation task
>   is usually the last thing the initial thread does, so it doesn't
>   matter whether it uses invokeLater or invokeAndWait.

**UPDATED**

The major issues I had were:

In you're escape key handler, if direction is 0, the pause option will never activate...

```
case KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE:
    direction = -direction;

    if (direction < 0) {
        add(options);
    } else {
        remove(options);
    }
```

The other thing I had to was call `revalidate`...

```
invalidate();
revalidate();
repaint();
```

Comment: Using `SwingUtilities`, how does it help?

Comment: All UI updates must be executed from in the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  The first test I run worked fine without them, but because I'm a Swing developer, I never modify a UI component from another Thread without it.

Comment: Alright. Another question - why are you setting the layout and adding the key listener inside `start` instead of `init`? The `start` method may be called more than once.

Comment: No reason really, just wanted to see if it made a difference.

Comment: Infact, you should probaly swap the contents of the `init` and `start` methods.  `init` should be used to "prepare" you applet, `start` is used to tell you the browser has requested that the applet "start" it's work...

Comment: Well, my code is a little more verbose and I still can't seem to catch the error. Perhaps you can: http://www.4shared.com/zip/niQ3CjN0/dragon.html?#

Comment: 4shared wants me to sign up and I'm not willing to do that, sorry

Comment: Not a problem. I uploaded my code on github. Hope that helps: https://github.com/aaditmshah/dragon

Comment: So it's painting the button and then that line erases the button? That line is supposed to draw an apple on the screen. It's a game of snake. The apple itself is really small. I don't think that would be able to cover the button would it?

Comment: @AaditMShah Sorry, it was my mistake, wasn't really paying attention :P, you should be able to simply add `revalidate` to the escape key handler (and fix the direction bug) and should be fine

Comment: There's no `revalidate` method in `java.applet.Applet`. Perhaps I should switch to Swing.

Comment: `revalidate` is inherited from `Component`.  I run your code with only that modification fine...